# JH7 IONIC and keycloak has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster

We are not able to log in using an IONIC app (running on localhost), because CORS policy blocked keycloak (external server).

We set application.yml with follow properties but it did not work :-(

```
configs:
  cors:
    # Allow Ionic for JHipster by default (* no longer allowed in Spring Boot 2.4+)
    allowed-origins: 'http://localhost:8100,http://localhost:9000,https://XXXXXXXXX,http://localhost:8100/callback'
    allowed-methods: '*'
    allowed-headers: '*'
    # exposed-headers: 'Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count'
    exposed-headers: 'Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-alert,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-error,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-params'
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
```

error log:

```
callback:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://XXXXXXXXXXX/auth/realms/pridea/protocol/openid-connect/token' from origin 'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: It looks like you need to add the URL to Keycloak too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on frontend and backend app,front use nodejs,i have similar problem,and i try lot of,in the end i turn

**[my-client]->Scope->Full Scope Allowed**

to'ON',then it works.i don't know  if this method make your app work,hope can help you.